# What is another way of Angular dependency injection using es6?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

Is there another way to make dependency injection in Angular controller's class except:

```
 constructor($http) {
   this.$http = $http;
 }
```

Sometimes there are too many services to use, that constructor is seems to be "a little big".

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: _"Sometimes there are too many services to use, that constructor is seems to be "a little big"_ And that would be a sign that your class has too many responsibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem exactly is, but you can of course just make your class constructor more readable:

```
constructor(
    private $http,
    private $scope
    private ...,
    private ...) {
    // no need to use this... = ...
}
```

If you're just concerned by the length and want to make it more unreadable:

```
static $inject = ["$http","$scope","otherDep", ..];
constructor(a,b,c,d,e,f) {
    this.$http = a;
    this.$scope = b;
    this.... = c;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: What is "private"? I can't find any documentation for that.

Comment: Using `private`, `protected` or `public` is shorthand for immediately creating a property instead of having to use `this.someProp = someProp`. But I now see that you use ES6, not typescript. I'm not sure if ES6 also implements this